# Using Cookies with Retrofit and Hilt and recommended architecture

Tags: android, kotlin, cookies, retrofit, dagger-hilt

I'm fairly new to Android and Java / Kotlin so I've been struggling to implement cookies in the recommended architecture. I looked in many places, read the documentation and watched many videos and everyone had such different ways to implement things that I was still confused. How does it all fit together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have thought this was such a common use case that I can't believe the answer isn't all over the net, but I've had to work hard to put all the pieces together. Below is what worked for me from the Repository down. I haven't included the database side of things since that is well documented in many places and I found it easy enough to follow (if anyone needs me to include that, let me know). I switched to Kotlin part way through because I could only find some parts of the answer in Java. My example is to log in a user and get basic profile details.

Repository sends login details to server and saves response in database then pulls that info to save as LiveData

```
package com.example.myapplication

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import com.example.myapplication.*
import com.example.myapplication.asDomainModel
import com.example.myapplication.asDBEntity
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import java.io.IOException
import javax.inject.Inject

class LoginRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val myDao: MyDao,
    private val myNetwork: Network
) {

    private val _profile: MutableLiveData<Profile> = MutableLiveData()
    val profile: LiveData<Profile>
        get() = _profile

    suspend fun login(name: String, password: String) {

        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

            // log in to server and get profile data
            val profileNWEntity = myNetwork.login("login", name, password)

            // process response
            when (profileNWEntity.status) {
                "PROFLOGINOK" -> {
                    // save profile in database then retrieve
                    myDao.insertProfile(profileNWEntity.asDBEntity())
                    _profile.postValue(myDao.getProfile(profileNWEntity.user).asDomainModel())
                }
                else -> {
                    throw IOException (profileNWEntity.status)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Retrofit endpoint defines the login process

```
package com.example.myapplication

import com.example.myapplication.ProfileNWEntity
import retrofit2.http.Field
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded
import retrofit2.http.POST

interface Network  {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("server_api")
    suspend fun login(
        @Field("action") action: String,
        @Field("name") name: String,
        @Field("pass") password: String
    ): ProfileNWEntity
}
```

Entity - used by Gson to parse the network response and by the repository to adapt for the database

```
package com.example.myapplication

import com.example.myapplication.AccountDBEntity
import com.example.myapplication.ProfileDBEntity

/**
 * Base profile response from network query
 */
data class ProfileNWEntity(
    val user: Int,
    val name: String,
    val status: String
)

// map the profile from network to database format
fun ProfileNWEntity.asDBEntity(): ProfileDBEntity {
    return ProfileDBEntity(
        id = user,
        name = name
    )
}
```

Retrofit class to enable inclusion of cookies (together with the interceptors included below, this comes from the work of tsuharesu and Nikhil Jha found at https://gist.github.com/nikhiljha/52d45ca69a8415c6990d2a63f61184ff)

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.content.Context
import dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ApplicationContext
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import javax.inject.Inject

class RetrofitWithCookie @Inject constructor(
    context: Context, // uses Hilt to inject the context to be passed to the interceptors
    gson: Gson
) {
    private val mContext = context
    private val gson = gson

    fun createRetrofit(): Retrofit {
        val client: OkHttpClient
        val builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        builder.addInterceptor(AddCookiesInterceptor(mContext)) // VERY VERY IMPORTANT
        builder.addInterceptor(ReceivedCookiesInterceptor(mContext)) // VERY VERY IMPORTANT
        client = builder.build()

        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("myServer URL") // REQUIRED
            .client(client) // VERY VERY IMPORTANT
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build() // REQUIRED
    }
}
```

Receiving Interceptor catches the inbound cookies and saves them in sharedpreferences

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.content.Context
import androidx.preference.PreferenceManager
import okhttp3.Interceptor
import okhttp3.Response
import java.io.IOException
import java.util.*

// Original written by tsuharesu
// Adapted to create a "drop it in and watch it work" approach by Nikhil Jha.
// Just add your package statement and drop it in the folder with all your other classes.
class ReceivedCookiesInterceptor(context: Context?) : Interceptor {
    private val context: Context?
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request())
        if (!originalResponse.headers("Set-Cookie").isEmpty()) {
            val cookies = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
                .getStringSet("PREF_COOKIES", HashSet()) as HashSet<String>?
            for (header in originalResponse.headers("Set-Cookie")) {
                cookies!!.add(header)
            }
            val memes = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit()
            memes.putStringSet("PREF_COOKIES", cookies).apply()
            memes.commit()
        }
        return originalResponse
    }

    init {
        this.context = context
    } // AddCookiesInterceptor()
}
```

AddCookies interceptor adds the cookie back into future requests

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.content.Context
import androidx.preference.PreferenceManager
import dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ActivityContext
import okhttp3.Interceptor
import okhttp3.Response
import timber.log.Timber
import java.io.IOException
import java.util.*

// Original written by tsuharesu
// Adapted to create a "drop it in and watch it work" approach by Nikhil Jha.
// Just add your package statement and drop it in the folder with all your other classes.
/**
 * This interceptor put all the Cookies in Preferences in the Request.
 * Your implementation on how to get the Preferences may ary, but this will work 99% of the time.
 */
class AddCookiesInterceptor(@ActivityContext context: Context?) : Interceptor {
    // We're storing our stuff in a database made just for cookies called PREF_COOKIES.
    // I reccomend you do this, and don't change this default value.
    private val context: Context?
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val builder = chain.request().newBuilder()
        val preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getStringSet(
            PREF_COOKIES, HashSet()
        ) as HashSet<String>?

        // Use the following if you need everything in one line.
        // Some APIs die if you do it differently.
        /*String cookiestring = "";
        for (String cookie : preferences) {
            String[] parser = cookie.split(";");
            cookiestring = cookiestring + parser[0] + "; ";
        }
        builder.addHeader("Cookie", cookiestring);
        */for (cookie in preferences!!) {
            builder.addHeader("Cookie", cookie)
            Timber.d("adding cookie %s", cookie)
        }
        return chain.proceed(builder.build())
    }

    companion object {
        const val PREF_COOKIES = "PREF_COOKIES"
    }

    init {
        this.context = context
    }
}
```

Hilt Module to tie it all together

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.content.Context
import com.example.myapplication.Network
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import dagger.hilt.InstallIn
import dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ApplicationContext
import dagger.hilt.components.SingletonComponent
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import javax.inject.Singleton

@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
class NetworkModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideNetwork(retrofit: Retrofit)
        : Network = retrofit.create(Network::class.java)

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofitWithCookie(
        @ApplicationContext context: Context,
        gson: Gson
    ): Retrofit = RetrofitWithCookie(context, gson).createRetrofit()

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideGson(): Gson = GsonBuilder()
        .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ") // used for parsing other responses
        .create()
}
```